# Having trouble using a controller with $scope on the component method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been studying 'Understanding Components' (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). I'm trying to change the main controller (MainCtrl) to use $scope rather than ctrl (as shown in the example). But no matter what I do, I can't get it to work.

Here's how I changed index.js

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('heroApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',  MainCtrl]);

    function MainCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.hero = {
        name: 'Spawn'
      };
    }
})(window.angular);
```

Index.html (just the body part):

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <b>Hero for {{hero}}</b><br>
  <hero-detail hero=hero></hero-detail>
</div>
```

The "heroDetail" part I left unchanged.

The "Hero for {{hero}}" line prints "Hero for {"name":"Spawn"}", so the binding is valid.
What am I missing? I feel like it's something obvious. But I've been working on it all day.
Thanks for your help.

Here's heroDetail.js:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
  bindings: {
    hero: '='
  }
});
})(window.angular);
```

And heroDetail.html:

```
<span>Name: {{$hero.name}}</span>
```

Comment: You are missing "". try this: `<hero-detail hero="hero"></hero-detail>`

Comment: I tried that, just now. Still the same result: Hero for {"name":"Spawn"}
Name:

Comment: can you add the code for hero-detail directive as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you are missing is that when using components, like you are for `hero-detail`, the controller instance is populated on the scope as `$ctrl` by default, but you can change this via the component options.

Since you haven't specified a different name, the correct markup for `heroDetail.html` is:

```html
<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>
```

Here is a full, working demo of the code.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('heroApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', MainCtrl]);

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.hero = {
      name: 'Spawn'
    };
  }
})(window.angular);


(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
    templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
    bindings: {
      hero: '='
    }
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="heroApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <b>Hero for {{hero}}</b><br>
    <hero-detail hero=hero></hero-detail>
  </div>

  <!-- an alternative way to specify a template -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="heroDetail.html">
    <span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>
  </script>
</div>
```

#### Additional Note

You should be aware that not only is AngularJS very old and out-of-date now, the use of `ng-controller` and injecting `$scope` is even more deprecated and discouraged. One reason is that it is impossible to migrate to Angular, which only uses components. If you use only components in AngularJS, you stand a fighting chance of migrating to use Angular in the future.